# Failed to run spring boot application when using aspectj as seperate module

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have an application which uses aspectj for logging purposes. Initially aspectj module was used inside my original application. Later I moved the aspectj module as a separate project and added that module dependency in my main project. Now when I run my main application, I am getting a run time exception which is shown below -

```
Mon Jan 09 2017 10:40:50 AM [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'xxxxManager': Error creating bean with name 'xxxManagerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'xxxx': Error creating bean with name 'xxxInspectorImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 51
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/afl/axidot/service/impl/xxxx.getxxx(Ljava/util/List;)D @15: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b3a 04b2 0275 2a2a 1904 b801 e54e 2ac6
    0x0000010: 0024 2ab6 00d6 1302 34b6 01f9 9900 17b8
    0x0000020: 0232 2d2a b600 d613 0234 b601 f1c0 0234
    0x0000030: b602 3e2a c600 4c2a b600 d613 0234 b601
    0x0000040: f999 003f b802 3206 bd00 033a 1519 1503
    0x0000050: 2a53 1915 0419 0453 1915 052d 53bb 027c
    0x0000060: 5919 15b7 027d 1302 27b6 022d 2ab6 00d6
    0x0000070: 1302 34b6 01f1 c002 34b6 0238 b802 58af
    0x0000080: 2a19 042d b802 7faf                    
; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxInspectorImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 51
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/afl/axidot/service/impl/xxxx.getxxxx(Ljava/util/List;)D @15: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b3a 04b2 0275 2a2a 1904 b801 e54e 2ac6
    0x0000010: 0024 2ab6 00d6 1302 34b6 01f9 9900 17b8
    0x0000020: 0232 2d2a b600 d613 0234 b601 f1c0 0234
    0x0000030: b602 3e2a c600 4c2a b600 d613 0234 b601
    0x0000040: f999 003f b802 3206 bd00 033a 1519 1503
    0x0000050: 2a53 1915 0419 0453 1915 052d 53bb 027c
    0x0000060: 5919 15b7 027d 1302 27b6 022d 2ab6 00d6
    0x0000070: 1302 34b6 01f1 c002 34b6 0238 b802 58af
    0x0000080: 2a19 042d b802 7faf    

Mon Jan 09 2017 10:40:50 AM [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
Mon Jan 09 2017 10:40:50 AM [main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
Mon Jan 09 2017 10:40:50 AM [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.afl.axidot.application.xxxxApplication.main(xxxxApplication.java:29)
```

When I do a maven install on my main application, it will run without issue. But if I made any changes in the main application, the above exception will occur. Again I have to do a maven install for running without issues. Here is my pom.xml of the aspectj project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.aspectj</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>logger</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    <aop.compliance.level>1.8</aop.compliance.level>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <complianceLevel>${aop.compliance.level}</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Below is the pom.xml of my main application(excluding other dependencies)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.xxx.axidot</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    <aop.compliance.level>1.8</aop.compliance.level>
    <sonar.host.url>http://172.16.2.31:9000/</sonar.host.url>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <drools.version>6.4.0.Final</drools.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.afl.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>xxx-xxx</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <complianceLevel>${aop.compliance.level}</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.xxx.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It works fine, when I move the aspectj files to my main application. I run using -noverify and worked, but it crashes jvm sometimes. What might be the issue here?